# Download script for Vim extension in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, indentation

I'm using the Vim extension in VSCode. In C++, I can indent blocks of code with the `>i{` and `>a{` commands. This can't be done in Python, as it uses indentation instead of brackets to delimite blocks of code. However, I found that it can be achieved by downloading [this](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037) script for Vim. The site says it has to be unpacked "in the vim runtime directory". Where is this directory in the case of the Vim extension?

Comment: VSC does not emulate Vim, it only defines a few of the keybindings, not the scripting engine

Comment: Just drop VSCode and use Vim.

Comment: @Enrico VSCode has some feature Vim doesn't, so VSCode with the Vim extension combines both.

Comment: @ARD, I wander what are these features. In Vim you can have plugins for everything, from [semantic completion](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/), to [integration with git](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter), from [useful snippets](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) to [extremely fast fuzzy file/buffer finder](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T). And much more. However, happy coding with MS stuff.